# How to Manipulate Sets of Buttons in React with UseStates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Hi I am new to react and trying to get buttons to light up when you press them, however they are in sets of buttons and **I'd like the other buttons in the set to not also light up when one is pressed.**

Currently I used UseState() and it just turns all buttons on and off. **What's the best practice work around to this, because creating 30 individual button functions does not seem practical.**
[image: Buttons]

```
  const [ticket, setTicket]=useState(false)


  const ticketHandler = () => {
    setTicket (!ticket);
  }
```

```
  <button onClick={ticketHandler} className={`${ticket? 'is-success': ''} button`}>1-5</button>
  <button onClick={ticketHandler} className={`${ticket? 'is-success': ''} button`}>6-9</button>
```

in this example both ticket '1-5' and ticket '6-9' light up green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store a value you could use in the state (I used '1-5') and then check against that.

```
function RadioButtonGroup() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');

  const handleClick = (value) => () => {
    setActive(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className={`${active === '1-5' ? 'is-active' : ''}`}
        onClick={handleClick('1-5')}
      >
        1-5
      </button>
      <button
        className={`${active === '6-9' ? 'is-active' : ''}`}
        onClick={handleClick('6-9')}
      >
        6-9
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am going to choose this as the answer, because I also want to program a button called "choose random" that will randomly set active some of the buttons, and pushing a random index onto the array will probably be easiest.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Ioannis you can still press multiple buttons at once, I think I need to set the array length to only allow a single button at once, let me try it.

Comment: Ok I've added     
```
   if (prevChecked.includes(value) ) {
          return prevChecked.filter((v) => v !== value);
        }
         else if (checked.length==0) {
          return [...prevChecked, value];
        }
```

still doesn't make the other buttons darken when one is selected but I think I'm close

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot got me confused. So you want one at a time to appear active, right? I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Of course you don't need to have an array, I thought you needed multiple checked. If you want one then it's simple. Updated the answer.

Comment: I did want to have multiple active, I guess this is beyond the question but. Imagine two rows of buttons

<button> 1-5 </button> <button> abcde </button>  ------------------- Row 2 <button> 6-9 </button>  <button> efgh </button> 
---- Now I want only one button in the first row to be activatable and only one in the second. I know I can just slightly rename your function and use it twice, but I'd like to use the array idea to see if I can get all the rows in one function.

Either way thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate `Button` component and keep the light-up logic in it. That will solve your issue.

```
const Button = ({ buttonText }) => {
  const [ticket, setTicket] = useState(false);

  const ticketHandler = () => {
    setTicket(!ticket);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={ticketHandler}
      className={`${ticket ? "is-success" : ""} button`}
    >
      {buttonText}
    </button>
  );
};
```

And create buttons like this:

```
<Button buttonText="1-5"/>
<Button buttonText="6-9"/>
```

Comment: He wants only 1 button to be lighted up at any given time

Comment: This works great, and thank you for teaching me about components, but like Cotldus said the other buttons can still be pressed.

Perhaps I can tinker around with the button component and some global variable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give a value to your button and pass it into your handler.

And assign the value to the ticket instead of making the ticket a Boolean

So,

```
const ticketHandler = (element) => {
    setTicket(element.value);

      };

const getClass = (condition) => ticket === condition ? 'is-success': ''
```

Button:

```
<button onClick={ticketHandler} value ="oneToFive" className={`${getClass("oneToFive")} button`}>1-5</button>
<button onClick={ticketHandler} value="sixToNine" className={`${getClass("sixToNine")} button`}>6-9</button>
```